# Must I delete existing profiles when setting up APNS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to get apns to work. I had a development and distribution provisioning profiles setup prior to working on apns. So I'm going through the steps in the apple docs titled "Creating and Installing the Provisioning Profile". I don't understand these steps:

1. Go to the provisioning portal in the iOS Dev Center.
2. **Create a new** provisioning profile that contains the App ID you registered for APNs.
3. **Modify any existing** profile before you download the new one.
   You have to modify the profile in some minor way (for example, toggle an option) for the portal to generate a new provisioning profile. If the profile isn't so “dirtied,” you're given the original profile without the push entitlements.

So - since I already have existing profiles, do I skip #2, and do #3 instead? Or do I have to delete my current profiles and create them from scratch, which would start me at #2 again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip #2 if you already have a profile.
If it doesn't work, you can always delete the existing profile and create a new one.